# Where to put the conf file for a script that runs logstash?

Tags: linux, logstash

I have a `logstash.conf` that reads my logs and send them to Elastic Search. I want to create a script that runs it continuously. I have seen [this page](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts).

I am placing the script in the `/etc/init.d/`

My question is : 
Is it important where I put my `logstash.conf`?

Any other remarks are good, because I am a newbie in this domain, it is my first time. Thanks

Comment: I deploy it via Puppet and RPM. It is installed as logstash.conf in /etc/logstash/conf.d

Comment: Does this means that I shall install it or just put it there?

Comment: You put it in there, but your logstash service should be pointed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your conf file in anywhere you want!

When you start logstash please use the absolute path point to the correct path!